# XHTML: DOCTYPE, link, and meta closed with forward slash?

Tags: syntax, tags, xhtml

I couldn't find an answer to my question using a search engine; some topics came close but did not quite answer my question. ChatGPT3 was making self-contradictory statements and was reasoning in circles. I hope you will abide my neophyte question.

I understand XHTML will one day replace HTML, so I decided to learn XHTML.
I understand one of the main differences between XHTML and HTML is that the stand-alone tags (probably not using the right nomenclature) that are closed in XHTML but not in HTML, i.e.:
**XHTML:** <img src="./demo.gif" />   <--- note the forward slash at the end
**HTML:** <img src="./demo.gif">       <--- note the absence of the forward slash at the end

Now, I was wondering if in XHTML the DOCTYPE tag and some header elements need to be closed with a forward slash as well. I.e.:

**<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" />** <--- note the forward slash at the end
<html>
<head>

**<meta charset="utf-8" />**  <--- note the forward slash at the end**
**<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />**  <--- note the forward slash at the end**
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet.css" />  **<--- note the forward slash at the end

</head>
<body>

Hello.

</body>
</html>

Thank you for your patience,

SilverC3ll

I have tried using correct XHTML syntax in the pre-HTML location of the document (DOCTYPE above <html>) and have tried to apply correct XHTML syntax to the meta and link elements. I have closed these tags with a forward slash. I expected that even though there may be an error in syntax the browser will still display the file as intended, so I cannot verify if whether my syntax is correct or not.

Comment: "ChatGPT3 was making self-contradictory statements and was reasoning in circles" — That's because it is a next-word-prediction-engine and not a search tool.

Answer (score -1):

> I understand XHTML will one day replace HTML

That understanding is incorrect. There is no expectation that XHTML will replace HTML. There was a time, around 20 years ago, when that expectation was widely held, but it has long since passed. It is however, a valid *alternative* syntax.

> `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" />` <--- note the forward slash at the end

In XHTML, the DOCTYPE **MUST NOT** have a forward slash at the end. However, the DOCTYPE can be omitted entirely. If you choose to use a DOCTYPE with XHTML, the correct form is exactly the same as with the HTML syntax: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

XHTML is not identified via the DOCTYPE, but by the content type in the HTTP content-type header. This should be `application/xhtml+xml`.  If you do not do this, the browser will treat your file as HTML, not XHTML, and your attempt to use XHTML will be in vain.

> `<meta charset="utf-8" />` <--- note the forward slash at the end**

Meta and link elements, and all other void elements, must be explicitly closed, either via the forward slash at the end, or by a close tag e.g. `</meta>` immediately following the start tag.

> I expected that even though there may be an error in syntax the browser will still display the file as intended, so I cannot verify if whether my syntax is correct or not.

If you use Firefox, it will not display the XHTML file at all if it contains a syntax error, and will only display an error message. Otherwise, use a validator. Again, make sure that the file is served with the correct content type.

Answer (score -1):

> I understand XHTML will one day replace HTML

It *was* expected to replace HTML in the early 2000s.

Then HTML 5 came along and work on XHTML 2 was discontinued.

Browsers aim to implement [the Living HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/). XHTML 1.x is obsolete.

> Now, I was wondering if in XHTML the DOCTYPE tag

The DOCTYPE is not a tag.

> some header elements need to be closed with a forward slash as well

In XHTML:

- **Every** element needs to be explicitly ended
- `<foo />` and `<foo></foo>` are equivalent

Note that if you serve your XHTML with a `text/html` Content Type then you should follow [the Appendix C compatibility guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines) which make the XHTML as close as possible to HTML so it doesn't break when parsed as HTML.

---

I strongly recommend *not* using XHTML.